# GraphQL Angular Apollo Client - Query with dynamic fields based on the checkbox value from the HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, graphql, graphene-python, apollo-angular

Below is the angular HTML and component logic, the 'doGetQuerySpecific()' method is called from html on click of 'Submit' on a form which has two checkboxes. I need to map these checkbox logic to the GQL query like shown in the component code. The logic which I want to implement is somehow satisfied below, but is this the optimal way? Any other way rather than using the if and else if conditions like this!!!

My .HTML:

```
            <form action="" (ngSubmit)="doGetQuerySpecific(p2)" #p2="ngForm">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="name" id="name" value="name" ngModel class="form-check-input">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="name">Name</label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="access" id="access" value="access" ngModel class="form-check-input">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="access">Access</label>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Get</button>
            </form>
```

MY .ts code:

```
doGetQuerySpecific(form: NgForm) {
    this.toHTML = 'Loading...'
    var name1 = false;
    var access1 = false;
    name1 = form.value.name;
    access1 = form.value.access;

    if (name1 == true && access1 == true) {
      var GET_Specific = gql`
      query {
        hello {
          id
          name
          access
        }
      }
      `;
    }

    else if (name1 == true && access1 == false) {
      var GET_Specific = gql`
      query {
        hello {
          id
          name
        }
      }
      `;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives ?

Comment: I am not able to use @include directive in apollo-angular, the server says it is a bad request. Do I have to change anything in the server side??

Comment: check if it is supported in your server, test in playground before coding

Comment: worked after sometime. Basically clearly structuring GQL query after trying in playground helped!!